# Product images aren't showing in mobile view in magento 2.2

Tags: magento2.2, product-images, product-page, mobile

Product Images aren't showing on the product page in **mobile view.** 
I am not able to find out what is the issue.

How to solve this.

Comment: Is there a different store view for mobile?

Comment: No. after adding this css image get proper on website .gallery-placeholder{ width: 100%; } I am using bootstrap 4.3.1